# OpenShift Create Configmap With a JSON value

Tags: groovy, openshift

I want to create a config map that uses a JSON object for it's value

The JSON object looks something like this, (`variable name = manifestJSON`)

```
{
    "appRepoVersionsMap": {
        "repoA": "1.0.0.131",
        "repoB": "1.0.0.7393"
    },
    "deployerVersion": "49",
    "openshiftConfigCommitId": "o76to87y"
}
```

Then I want to create a configmap that takes this JSON object and adds it as a value of the configmap.

The command I am trying to make it work is

```
def osCmd = "create configmap manifest-config" +
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_config_branch=${envVars.OS_CONFIG_BRANCH}" +
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_server=${envVars.OPENSHIFT_SERVER_URL}" 
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_manifest=${manifestJSON}"
os.call(osCmd)
```

OpenShift client gives the following error:

`10:23:37 error: cannot add key manifest.os_manifest, another key by that name already exists: map[manifest.os_config_branch:deployment-orchestrator manifest.os_server:<snipped>, manifest.os_manifest:appRepoVersionsMap:repoA:1.0.0.131 ].`

So either groovy or OpenShift sees the JSON object within the JSON object and can't handle it.

I am trying to avoid using `--from-file` because I will have to write to disk and then run the command and I am afraid this will cause issues in a Jenkins environment with multiple deploys to multiple projects taking place.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being rather simple and I was overthinking the character escapes while trying various solutions.

In order to use a JSON as value when creating a configmap (or a secret) is to add `''` around the JSON object itself

```
def osCmd = "create configmap manifest-config" +
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_config_branch=${envVars.OS_CONFIG_BRANCH}" +
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_server=${envVars.OPENSHIFT_SERVER_URL}" 
        " --from-literal=manifest.os_manifest='${manifestJSON}'" // <----- single quotes
os.call(osCmd)
```

That allowed the configmap creation and I confirmed from the OpenShift side that the configmap is present with the manifest values I was expecting.